# Код для системы тикетов не удаляет созданный тикет

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Начало кода работает отлично, но конец кода отвечающая за удаление созданного тикета не работает

Код:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ticket(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Система Тикетов',
        description = 'Нажми  что бы создать тикет.',
        color = 0
    )
    embed.set_footer(text="ticket system")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")
    def check(reaction, user):
        return str(reaction) == '' and ctx.author == user
    await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
    chan = await user.guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {user}')
    role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="@everyone")
    await chan.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False, add_reactions=False, embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False, external_emojis=False)
    await chan.set_permissions(user, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Тикеты",
        description="Нажмите :lock: что бы закрыть тикет",
        color=0x00FFFF
    )
    embed.set_footer(text="Система тикетов")
    msg = await chan.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")

    await msg.add_reaction("")
    def check(reaction, user):
        return str(reaction) == '' and ctx.author == user
    await user.guild.delete_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {user}')
```

Ошибка:

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `discord.Guild` нет метода `delete_text_channel`. Чтобы удалить канал нужно найти его среди других по имени и вызвать метод `delete()`:

```
channel_to_delete = list(filter(lambda channel: channel.name == f'ticket - {user}', user.guild.text_channels))[0]
await channel_to_delete.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await chan.delete()
```

Вот тебе такой фрагмент

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]